# Difference between using a generic type and using its upper bound type directly as the parameter type in a function

Tags: generics, kotlin, parameters

In Kotlin, all types are treated as classes.
Suppose there is an upper bound class definition:

```
open/abstract class UpperBound(...) { ... }
```

Does it make any difference to define a generic function

```
fun <T: UpperBound> function(param: T) { ... }
```

compared to defining a function using the upper bound directly

```
fun function(param: UpperBound) { ... }
```

since inside `function`, when calling other functions with `param` as a parameter, it will be treated directly as an `UpperBound`; and when calling methods on `param`, all calls will be performed on the object's actual overridden methods?

---

**Update**: sorry the following is a wrong example of the question. Just ignore it.

If there is no difference, what's the purpose of defining the library functions such as `run` in this more complicated way

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block()
}
```

instead of

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <R> Any?.run(block: Any?.() -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block()
}
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example of `run` is a great one. If you define this function with `Any?` as the receiver of both `run` and its `block` parameter (let's call this `anyRun`), you will receive an object of type `Any?` inside the receiver, and you'll only be able to call `toString` and similar methods on it, any only after a smart cast:

```
foo.anyRun {
    this?.toString() // only basic Any? methods visible here, since `this` is of type Any?
    this?.hashCode()
}
```

This will happen regardless of what the type of `foo` is.

On the other hand, with the original generic implementation, you'll get back your instance *with its original type* inside the lambda, e.g.:

```
"hello".run {
    this.length // String methods and properties available on this
}
```

Comment: Sorry I realized that I have made a mistake that the second example doesn't correspond with the first question. So could you answer the first question please?

Comment: This is a really good point demonstrating how capturing call-site types into type parameter makes things better!